# error in parsing parameter using php

Tags: php, mysql

This code showing the output as :

> string(59) "{"status":{"message":"error parsing
>   parameter","value":14}}"

but when instead of "`file_get_contents`" only "`echo`" is used, it shows correct url as output : `http://ws.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?lat=20.992&lng=73.314&username=****`

what is going wrong here ?

```
 <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "*******";
    $password = "*************";
    $dbname = "id1116502_kk";

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     }
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    //remove limit 1 is you want multiple data.  
    $sql = "SELECT degree_n, minute_n,degree_e, minute_e FROM coordinates  ORDER BY id DESC limit 1 "; 
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $deg_e = "";
    $min_e = "";
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $deg_n = $row["degree_n"];
            $min_n = $row["minute_n"];
            $deg_e = $row["degree_e"];
            $min_e = $row["minute_e"];

           $url =  file_get_contents('http://ws.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?lat=$deg_n.$min_n&lng=$deg_e.$min_e&username=****');

            var_dump($url);

        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();

    ?>
```

Comment: you are using single quotes in tour `file_get_contents`

Comment: thnx...solved...

Comment: Well, it's impossible that something like `echo 'http://ws.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?lat=$deg_n.$min_n&lng=$deg_e.$min_e&username=****';` parses the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using single quotes in your `file_get_contents`

```
 // change this to double quotes
 $url =  file_get_contents('http://ws.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?lat=$deg_n.$min_n&lng=$deg_e.$min_e&username=krunal123');
```

[for more info check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: [more information here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)